Microsoft Graph Authentication fails locally for Azure Functions App
For our Azure Durable Powershell Functions we want to migrate the Microsoft Graph authentication from a App Registration with a certificate to a System-assigned managed identity.
In profile.ps1 the following is enabled
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
        Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
        Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}

I enabled the Identity in the Functions App and assigned a few Microsoft Graph API permissions (App Roles) to this System-assigned managed identity.
In a Function activity I connect to Microsoft Graph with:
Connect-MgGraph -Identity

And then do a simple Get-MgUser call as a test.
When deployed the Azure Functions App this test code works just fine when the Orchestrator is triggered and the Get-MgUser returns the expected user object.
However, I struggle to get this working in my local develop environment (Visual Studio Code). Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction to get this working.
My own (developer) account has all the required permissions in Azure (Global Admin Role activated)
I have the following extensions installed in VS Code: "Azure Account", Azure Functions" and "Durable Functions Monitor" + a few other less relevant
According to this link and this one I should be able to use my own Azure account to execute and debug the Functions locally.
In VS Code I also signed-in to azure via F1 > Azure: Sign-in
But local the code always hangs for a while at the Connect-MgGraph -Identity and then fails.
I added a break point and executed Connect-MgGraph -Identity in the terminal myself and it looks like the GET command to retrieve the token is lost and tries to connect to a APIPA IP address. GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=REDACTED
It tries this a few times and then gives up. obviously this fails, but I can't figure out why it tries to this APIPA IP instead of the correct address.
Below the log output

[DBG]: [Process:45480]: [PowerShellManager1]: PS
C:\Development\IT-Automation-AzureFunctions>> Connect-MgGraph
-Identity                                              ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [
https://graph.microsoft.com ] ParentRequestId:  False MSAL 4.56.0.0
MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-04-08
19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] MSAL MSAL.CoreCLR
with assembly version '4.56.0.0'.
CorrelationId(642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d) False MSAL
4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-04-08 19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] ===
AcquireTokenForClientParameters === SendX5C: False ForceRefresh: False
False MSAL 4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows
10.0.22631 [2024-04-08 19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d]
=== Request Data === Authority Provided? - True Scopes - https://graph.microsoft.com Extra Query Params Keys (space separated)

ApiId - AcquireTokenForClient IsConfidentialClient - True SendX5C - False LoginHint ? False HomeAccountId - False CorrelationId -
642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d UserAssertion set: False
LongRunningOboCacheKey set: False Region configured:

False MSAL 4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows
10.0.22631 [2024-04-08 19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] === Token Acquisition
(ClientCredentialRequest) started:
Scopes: https://graph.microsoft.com
Authority Host: login.microsoftonline.com False MSAL 4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-04-08
19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] [Region discovery]
Not using a regional authority. False MSAL 4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET
6.0.28 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-04-08 19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] [Instance Discovery] Skipping
Instance discovery because it is disabled.
False MSAL 4.56.0.0 MSAL.CoreCLR .NET 6.0.28 Microsoft Windows
10.0.22631 [2024-04-08 19:34:57Z - 642b2d8c-7db4-4033-9b7d-a7d98ee4d59d] [ClientCredentialRequest]
Sending Token response to client credential request endpoint ...
Request [9992998c-517a-4311-8431-6f065f8209bb] GET
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=REDACTED
Metadata:REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id:9992998c-517a-4311-8431-6f065f8209bb
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Identity/1.10.3 (.NET 6.0.28; Microsoft Windows
10.0.22631) client assembly: Azure.Identity Request [9992998c-517a-4311-8431-6f065f8209bb] exception
Azure.RequestFailedException: A connection attempt failed because the
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
established connection failed because connected host has failed to
respond. (169.254.169.254:80)


See if following helps : https://www.modernendpoint.com/managed/troubleshooting-microsoft-graph-app-registration-errors/

Thx, but that post is related to the authentication through a app registration which is what we are doing now and want to replace with a System assigned managed identity

What is the difference?  A Network has a Password Server and all machines use the Password Server to authenticate.  Windows Network is Secure and all machines have to be recognized on the Network to allow two machines to connect.  Once connected the credentials are the same on client and server.  A credential has a ROLE.  I think you want to use the ROLE for the managed identity which comes from the Network Credentials.

It solves a security issue. With a App Registration a developer needs either the Client Secret or the Certificate of that App Reg. When a developer leaves his account will be disabled, but he potentially still has access to the secret/certificate and therefor still has access to all API permissions until the secret/certificate gets rotated which potentially has impact on the Function App.
A system assigned managed identity solves this as the API permissions are linked to the Function App for production and development is done under the developer account which no longer works when he leaves.

This is a token/cookie issue and how long the cookie is valid.  The token is a random number obtained from the certificate.

It is a client auth certificate so developer will have it locally installed and private key is local and can be exported if he wants. The App Reg has the public cert only to validate the if the auth cert is valid.
But this is all out of the scope of the actual question, we already have cert based authentication and want (need) to move to a System Managed Identity for prod and for local development the dev needs to use his own account as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#authenticate-the-client.

The only differences are shown in the two example at following.  The User ID is used in the first example and no User ID is shown in the second : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#examples-1

For running the Powershell Function code locally the managed identity authentication won't work for the Visual Studio logged in user, You will need to implement Interactive Authentication by using the codes below:-
Code1:-
Reference here. by darrenjrobinson

Import-Module MSAL.PS

$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com" 
$scope = "User.ReadWrite" 
$clientID = "xxxxxxxx1435cb" 
$tenantID = "domain name" 
$myUPN = "xxxxx@outlook.com" 

$myAccessToken = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID `
        -TenantId $tenantID `
        -Scopes "$($resource)/$($scope)" `
        -LoginHint $myUPN 


Output:-

Code2 with Client Certificate:-
Reference here. by darrenjrobinson
Import-Module MSAL.PS
$clientID = 'AzureADAppClientID'
$tenantID = 'AADTenantID'
$ClientCertificate = Get-Item "Cert:\Local\My\$($thumbPrint)"
$myAccessToken = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -TenantId $tenantID -ClientCertificate $ClientCertificate
$myAccessToken.AccessToken | Get-JWTDetails

